# android changing color of group in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to take an expandable list view that I have already created and change the color of the background of one of the items in the list of groups. I only want to change the color of the entry in the main list, not its drop down children, aka the part that you click on to expand or hide the other parts. I think getGroupView will do this, but I can't figure out how to make this work. If this is the proper method to use, can someone explain how to use it? If there is a better way, what is it?

[Edit] I played around with it some more, and figured out how to use getGroupView somewhat, but I am still having a problem. What I am doing to my understanding should be only changing the color of a single entry, but instead it changes them all. Here is the code:

```
    View listViewRow = findViewById(R.layout.menu_item);
    listViewRow = myNewAdapter.getGroupView(2, false, listViewRow, expandView);
    listViewRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

where menu_item is the name of the layout file that I am using for the groups in the expandable list, and expandView is the expandableListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this in extended BaseExpandableListAdapter class

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
   }

   TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
   tvGroupName.setText(list.get(groupPosition).getYear() +" COLLECTION");

   return convertView;
  }
```

OR refrer [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/)

Comment: I may not entirely be understanding what you are telling me to do. This code seems to be dong nothing, and it doesn't change anything when I try to use it. What I think I need to do is find a way to reference each individual view that makes up the drop down menu super list.

Comment: I guess a better way of saying things would be that this code seems to be simply changing a view you already have, but I don't even have the view I need to change. I need to get that view.

Comment: I am pretty new to android programming, but it seems like I should be able to use the ExpandableListAdapter that is already there instead of having to make my own. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: if you don't want to change layout of group and child view than you can use default but want to change layout of groups and childs view than you have make your own BaseExpandableListAdapter class. and you can bind data on it with your views.

Comment: I found the solution in my case (Change Expandable group Item background when expanded, and again changed to its previous state when collapsed), I will add a complete example after success.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

- if u want to change color of headerlist  change in headerlist.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@color/colorRed">
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

  -if u want to change color of childlist change in childlist.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"

   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15dp"
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Answer (score -3):

Put this line, where you want to show a different color:

```
- android:textColor="#a60704"
```

Give your any color in place of:

```
- #a60704
```